# Checkbox and caption without line break

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, checkbox

I can't place `checkbox` and "Remember me" in one line using laravel and bootstrap. There is a line break between `checkbox` and "Remember me" but I don't want that line break.

My code:

```
{{Form::open(['route'=>'sessions.store','class'=>'form-horizontal'])}}


    <div class = 'form-group'>
        {{Form::label('email','Email',['class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label'])}}
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{Form::email('email',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
        {{$errors->first('email')}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'form-group'>
        {{Form::label('password','Password',['class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label'])}}
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{Form::password('password',['class'=>'form-control'])}}
        {{$errors->first('password')}}
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div class = 'form-group'>
        <div class='col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4'>
            {{Form::checkbox('remember-me',1,null,['class'=>'checkbox'])}}
            {{Form::label('remember-me','Remember me')}}
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class = 'form-group'>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
        {{Form::submit('Login',['class'=>'btn btn-default'])}}
        </div>
    </div>

{{Form::close()}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're generating this markup for the 'Remember me' checkbox:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
        <input class="checkbox" name="remember-me" type="checkbox" value="1">
        <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

While this is the expected markup for the default Twitter Bootstrap checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" value="1"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

To fix this, you can use this Blade excerpt in your view:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
        <label>
            {{ Form::checkbox('remember-me', 1) }}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```